# Can I update Google Form questions with a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have tons of Google Forms for a project and each one has the same sections and questions, just different choices. Every time I want to update a question, I have to change each form individually which takes a lot of time. I was wondering if there's a way to link a Form to a Sheet so I can change the question in the spreadsheet and it'll update in every single form connected.

Answer (score 0):

One option I could suggest is to create a [**container-bound script**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) in your Google Sheets to update the questions for multiple Google Forms using Apps Script.

---

## **Example Sheet:**

[image]

[image]

> We have a Google Sheet with 2 Sheets named "Questions" and "Forms" respectively.
>
> **Sheet:Questions** contains the list of questions available in your Google Forms. To Update column can be used as a flag to determine which questions you want to update in the Google Forms.
>
> **Sheet:Forms** contains the list of Google Forms Ids' where you want the questions to be updated.

---

## **Example Apps Script Code:**

```
function updateFormsQuestions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Forms");
  var questionsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Questions");
  
  //Get the list of forms to update
  var formsList = formsSheet.getRange(2,1,formsSheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  Logger.log(formsList);
  
  //Get the list of questions to update
  var questionIndex = [];
  var qCheckbox = questionsSheet.getRange(2,2,questionsSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(qCheckbox);
  
  qCheckbox.forEach(function(currentValue, index){ 
                    if(currentValue[0] == true)questionIndex.push(index);
  });
  Logger.log(questionIndex);

  //Open Form and get all items
  for( var i = 0; i < formsList.length; i++){
   
    var forms = FormApp.openById(formsList[i][0]);
    var items = forms.getItems();

    //Update question
    questionIndex.forEach(function(index){
                          Logger.log(index);
                          Logger.log(questionsSheet.getRange(index + 2, 1).getValue());
                          items[index].setTitle(questionsSheet.getRange(index + 2, 1).getValue());
    });
    
  }
}
```

**What it Does?**

1. Get the list of Google Forms Ids' under `Sheet:Forms`
2. Get all checkbox values under `Sheet:Questions` starting from `Cell B2`.
3. Check each checkbox values if set to true, then push the current index to the `questionIndex` array. (Note that in javascript array index starts from zero).
4. Open each forms listed in step 1, one-by-one using for-loop using [FormApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openbyidid). Then get all items of the current forms using [.getItems()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getitems). It will give you an array of items available in your form (this may represent your questions in your form).

> Forms items can be accessed as an array. Hence it should start from zero. (Question 1 = index 0, Question 2 = index 1 ... so on)

5. Update the questions in the current item using [.setTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#settitletitle). The new title will be based on the cell value under Sheet:Questions column A. You can get the value of the cell using [.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) assuming you already selected the correct cell range using [.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column).

> Notice that we increment the row index by 2 when getting the cell value `questionsSheet.getRange(index + 2, 1).getValue()`. Cell rows and columns starts from 1 in sheets, if we want to access `Cell A3, row = 3; col = 1`. The index that we saved earlier in Step 3 starts from zero (since we used an array). If you are curious why we increment 2 instead of 1. The reason is because we also adjusted the indexing when we start getting the checkbox values from row 2 instead of row 1 in Step 2.
>
> `Sheet:Questions` Column C will show you the indexing of the `qCheckbox` array, while Column D will show you the indexing of sheets when accessing rows.

---

## **Output:**

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

---

**Additional References:**

[Forms Service - allows scripts to create, access and modify Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms)

[Spreadsheet Service - allows scripts to create, access, modify Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)